# Any way to change colour of the Code Insight red 'underline' in Delphi2007 IDE?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2007

I hope the question says it all, really. I use the old Turbo Pascal type colours (navy blue background and white, yellow text etc) in all my Delphi IDEs, including D2007. I'm sufficiently colourblind that I can't really make out the red squiggly lines in my code - but I find the feature really useful when I do notice them.

I've tried switching to a much lighter background but it doesn't feel right - I've been using the classic background in Borland/Inprise/Borland/Codegear/Embarcadero products since about '91. :-)

Does anyone know of any slight-of-hand that would get the colour of that red line changed (white or yellow would be great)?

EDIT: Okay, further to this then - although I can't move most of my existing stuff to D2009 just yet, is this an option I ***CAN*** set in D2009?

EDIT : Seems like it can't be done, in 2007 or 2009. **Let's hope it gets picked up for the next version**. Bob S's link to the qc document for it can be used to help persuade Embarcadero - I opened that case last year when I first struggled to find a solution for this. In the interests of marking something as an answer, I'll tick Bob's reply.

In the meantime, I think I'm going to have to change my background colour to something that I can see the red against. Oh well. :-)

Comment: I don't see an option to change it in D2009, but I hope you'll find your answer. Perhaps send an E-Mail to CodeGear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can vote here:

http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=61780

Comment: Thanks - but that QC entry was made by ME, last year, when I first started using D2007 and found this to be a problem. :-)
Good to see it's still 'on the books' somewhere, though.

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).